# django - prepending a field in the query set that doesn't exist in the model

Tags: python, django

I have a model that reads from a pre-existing university database.  The username is stored as the students id.  I'm not able to add a new column to the database in a save or I could use a save function in my model.

```
class Student(models.Model):
        student_id = models.IntegerField(db_column = 'Student_ID', primary_key = True)
        statusid = models.IntegerField(db_column = 'StatusID')
        fname = models.CharField(db_column = 'Student_First_Name', max_length = 35)
        lname = models.CharField(db_column = 'Student_Last_Name_Formatted' , max_length = 40)



        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = '[Student]'
```

What i'm trying to do is take the username in a query and match it up with another field that is umich.edu/student_id as a primary key.

I'm defining the request in one function as:

```
def user_list(request):
    student = Student.objects.all()
```

passing in the argument for students to my template with a POST to the form.

In my next view that gets posted

```
def criteria(request):
    user = request.POST.get('student_id')
    print(user)
    student = CourseCriteria.objects.get(universitystudentid = request.POST.get('student_id'))
```

My print/post of user is coming through correctly as the student id, but I need to prepend umich.edu/ to the student_id in the queryset.  How can I accomplish this without being able to add that field to my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your problem, I suppose that it is not as simple as:

```
def criteria(request):
    user = request.POST.get('student_id')
    student = CourseCriteria.objects.get(universitystudentid='umich.edu/%s'%user)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gives the error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.  Basically that's what i want, my user id is stored in the database as 12345 in one table and in another table it's umich.edu/12345.  I need my query set to prepend umich.edu/ to the student_id in the Student table.

Comment: Is the `user` variable clean? Have you tried `user = user.strip()`?

Comment: I figured it out / was trying to divide, so i had to add //.  If you edit your answer to use // i'll mark it correct.

Comment: The '/' is inside a string, so it cannot be interpreted as a divide sign. Anyway I will update my answer to a cleaner form.

Comment: strange i couldn't get it to work with the %s for the string, // does work for me.